# Parent-child facets

Tags: search

I am using facets and I want to have one facet with Parent term and when clicking on one parent term,another facet to appear with the children of the clicked taxonomy term.How is this possible to do?thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with your own widget. Making it collapsible. You would need use some Jquery. and facet api.

Together with

[Taxonomy Sort](https://drupal.org/project/facetapi_taxonomy_sort)

> Add the ability to sort taxonomy facets by their term weight.
>   Essentially takes the code from http://drupal.org/node/1361284 and
>   implements as a standalone module.

Then creating your own widget, you could customize it even more.

```
/**
* Implements hook_facetapi_widgets()
*/
function example_facetapi_widgets() {
  return array(
    'example_select' => array(
      'handler' => array(
        'label' => t('Select List'),
        'class' => 'ExampleFacetapiWidgetSelect',
        'query types' => array('term', 'date'),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
?>
```

and also look into

```
/**
* Implements hook_facetapi_sort_info().
*/
function example_facetapi_sort_info() {
  $sorts = array();
  $sorts['random'] = array(
    'label' => t('Random'),
    'callback' => 'example_facetapi_sort_random',
    'description' => t('Random sorting.'),
    'weight' => -50,
  );

  return $sorts;
}

/**
* Sort randomly.
*/
function example_facetapi_sort_random(array $a, array $b) {
  return rand(-1, 1);
}
?>
```